# Proguard files not being created

Tags: android-proguard

I have several projects in Android Studio.  I am using
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
in my gradle script.  I have updated Android Studio to the latest version and use the latest version of build tools.  However, the proguard files, for example, mapping.txt, are never generated.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. The steps are:

1. Create a new empty project in Android Studio, and the default file, proguard-rules.pro, is created in the app folder.
2. Outside of Android Studio (e.g. Windows Explorer), copy proguard-rules.pro to the app directory.
3. It will show up in your project when it is re-opened.
4. Edit proguard-rules.pro as explained in the comments in the proguard-rules file.
5. Generate your apk and you'll see that the mapping.txt and other proguard files are created.